# Java XML Transformer : Empty elements in long notation instead of short

Tags: java, xml, transformer-model

I have created a conversion tool to add some information to an existing xml file.
This is done by using DOM and the Transformer class.
The output file will be processed by third party software.
This TPS needs the empty tags from the input and outputfile in Long Notation.

Unfortunately, transformer class always change them to short notation.
Is there a way to prevent this from happenning?

I have been searching various sites, but haven't found a solution that really fits my needs.

Please help,
Thanks,
Kind regards,
Maarten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the `DOM` to `StAXResult`.

For instance,

```
 XMLOutputFactory factory=XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
 XMLStreamWriter writer=factory.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
 StAXResult result=new StAXResult(writer);
 trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc),result);
```

Comment: Is there a way to only output certain parts in long notation?  In particular, I need <SOAP-ENC:Array> elements to always be output in long notation, but the standard Java xml transformer only outputs them in long notation if there are one or more items in the array; if they are empty, it outputs them in short notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
                XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
                XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(System.out);
                StAXResult result = new StAXResult(writer);
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), result);
```